# Going from hana::tuple_t to hana::tuple

Tags: c++, boost-hana, typelist

I have a `hana::tuple_t<int, char, double, float>`, and I want to use this to create a `hana::tuple<int, char, double, float>`.

I thought that using `hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>` would transform the `hana::tuple_t<int, char, double, float>` into a `hana::tuple<int, char, double, float>`; but that is not the case since the following always fails:

```
auto oType = hana::tuple_t<int, char, double, float>;

BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_ASSERT(
    hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(oType)
    ==
    hana::make_tuple(1, 'C', 1.0, 1.0f)
);
```

I've also tried using `hana::transform`, but with no luck (although I suspect I'm doing it wrong):

```
auto vecs = hana::transform(typeList, [](auto t) {
    return typename decltype(t)::type{};
});
```

So, how do I go about turning a hana::tuple_t into a hana::tuple?

Comment: Default initialization will yield a value of `0`, not `1` (or `1.0`, or `'C'`). Have you tried comparing it to the tuple `hana::make_tuple(0, '\0', 0.0, 0.0f)`?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. The compiler errors up with :Severity  static_assert failed "hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(oType) == hana::make_tuple(0, 0.0, 0.0f)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you really want here is something like

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

constexpr auto types = hana::tuple_t<int, char, double, float>;
using Tuple = decltype(hana::unpack(types, hana::template_<hana::tuple>))::type;
// Tuple is hana::tuple<int, char, double, float>
// Now you can create such a tuple as you wish:
Tuple ts{1, 'x', 2.2, 3.4f};
```

Things like `hana::template_` and `hana::metafunction` were built precisely to make this interoperation with types easy.

Comment: You mentioned `hana::metafunction` and interoperation with types, so I assume that's what you'd use to go in the opposite direction (from the type `hana::tuple<A,B,C>` to the value `hana::type_t<A,B,C>`). Can you elaborate on how you actually do that?

Answer (score 4):

`hana::tuple_t` is just a template variable that is itself already a `hana::tuple` so converting to `hana::tuple` won't change anything.

```
template <typename ...T>
constexpr hana::tuple<hana::type<T>...> tuple_t{};
```

As mentioned in the comments, your call to `hana::transform` default initializes each member so you would expect values such as 0 for integral types.

Also, you are using `BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_ASSERT` which checks compile-time values only. Raw `int`, `char`, `double`, and `float` values will not be `constexpr`.

`BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT` works for run-time values:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

constexpr auto types = hana::tuple_t<int, char, double, float>;

struct init_from_type_fn
{
  template <typename Type>
  constexpr auto operator()(Type) const
  {
    return typename Type::type{};
  }
};

constexpr init_from_type_fn init_from_type{};

int main()
{
  BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(
    hana::equal(
      hana::transform(types, init_from_type),
      hana::make_tuple(0, '\0', 0.0, 0.0f)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is MSVC w/ Clang. It just doesn't like this code, but it runs fine on my vm using Clang.

Comment: What is the error? Maybe it isn't specifyng `c++14`? I don't use MSVC but I've heard of people using Hana with it.

Comment: It's a `clang frontend command failed due to signal use`. From what I gathered, the compiler is getting confused when it tries to put everything together. There's no way to throw a `-v` afaik, so I've considered it a brick wall.

Comment: Hana's wiki has some stuff about it. Hope it helps... https://github.com/boostorg/hana/wiki/Setting-up-Clang-on-Windows