# How to declare a member variable using Boost.Hana

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I've previously used a little of the Boost.MPL library in the past, and I'm trying to get to know Boost.Hana a little more. I seem to be running into a complete misunderstanding of the library.

I would like to instantiate an object with an arbitrary number of template arguments, create a tuple of objects based on those types as a member, and iterate over or otherwise use that tuple later.

What I've run into is that all of the examples and documentation deal solely with making tuples in functions, and not with actually making a type that I could use for a class member.

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar { void apply() const {} };

template<typename ...T>
struct Foo
{
   template<typename _T>
   using Bar = Bar<_T>;

   static constexpr auto tuple = boost::hana::transform(
      boost::hana::tuple_t<T...>,
      boost::hana::template_<Bar>);

   void apply()
   {
      boost::hana::for_each(
         tuple,
         [](auto const& bar)
         {
            bar.apply();
         });
   }
};
```

The error I get:

```
error: 'const struct boost::hana::type_impl<Bar<int> >::_' has no member named 'apply'
```

So tuple doesn't contain objects of `Bar<T>` type, but rather, objects of the boost::hana "object that represents a type" type.

I can make a tuple like so:

```
boost::hana::tuple<T...> m_tuple;
```

I get pretty close to what I want, but how do I integrate `boost::hana::transform` into the declaration of `m_tuple`?

I don't understand how to go from the variable that `boost::hana::transform` returns to a type I can use for a member of the class. Is this even possible? Or should I be looking at Boost.MPL?

I did see [a presentation given at cppnow 2017](http://ldionne.com/cppnow-2017-fun-with-boost-hana/#/1/5) which had an example of moving from MPL to Hana:

**MPL**:

```
using Ptrs = mpl::transform<Types, std::add_pointer<mpl::_1>>::type;
// -> mpl::vector<int*, void*, char*, long*, void*>
```

**Hana**:

```
auto Ptrs = hana::transform(Types, [](auto t) {
   return hana::traits::add_pointer(t);
});
// -> hana::tuple_t<int*, void*, char*, long*, void*>
```

But the MPL version gives me a type I can use to make class members, where as the Hana version gives me a variable that can't be a class member and that I can't seem to use to make class members of a type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584566/2417774

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

Now that I go back to the documentation I see that this is explained in several places, but I didn't catch it. I think I was confused by the MPL to Hana comparison too much. Maybe if it included the "Unwrap the result with decltype(...)::type" step it would have been more one-to-one.

Comment: @llonesmiz, your comment gave the push I needed. If you post an answer, I'll accept it, or this could be marked as a duplicate I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that [`hana::tuple_t`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1tuple.html#a1997546daf58a48cc15498d338a03da3) is an alias for a tuple where all of the members are wrapped in [`hana::type`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html).

The answer linked in the comments is a good solution, but here is an example that steps further away from MPL style template metaprogramming. It's more concise and doesn't hide the fact that it is relying on default construction.

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename T>
struct Bar { void apply() const { } };

template <typename ...T>
struct Foo
{
  void apply()
  {
    hana::for_each(
      hana::tuple<Bar<T>...>{},
      [](auto const& bar)
      {
        bar.apply();
      });
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo<int, float, char>{}.apply();
}
```